# through jython I would like to execute a python file from java and also pass the parameter file necessary to execute the python file

Tags: java, python, parameters, jython

```
package Test_2.Test_2;

import org.python.core.PyInstance;  // importo jython

public class PythonHello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         
              PythonCaller ie = new PythonCaller();  // istanzio la classe pythoncaller
              
              JsonMakeString JsonString = new JsonMakeString();  
                      
              String StringForPython = JsonString.JsonString();
              
              ie.execfile("MAIN.py");   

              PyInstance hello = ie.createClass("Main", StringForPython);  // Main is the class 

              hello.invoke("Run");   // Run is the method I want to run
              
           }

}
```

I would like to understand what I have to do to pass the parameter needed to instantiate the Main class

Comment: What are PythonCaller and JsonMakeString?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182584/how-do-i-call-java-methods-from-jython-that-is-executed-by-the-java-class